# exclude favicon from rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got these lines in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

These rewrite rules work fine, but i've got a favicon.ico icon in the root of this server, but I can't address it with these rewrite rules.

How can I rewrite this .htaccess file to only rewrite if it's not a request for the favicon.ico file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an exception to your rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond ^([^/]+)/?$ !^favicon\.ico
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

That said I'd like to mention that unless there are good reasons to use `.htaccess` style configuration files you should put such rewriting rules into the main server configuration. That is much faster and easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid your solutions doesn't work. It still redirects my url (http://www.domain.com/favicon.ico) to http://www.domain.com/page=favicon.ico

Comment: I made a small modification to the RewriteCond, I guess the leading slash in there was wrong. Sorry, I have limited experience in `.htaccess` style files. Doing such stuff in the main server configuration is always preferred unless there are very specific reasons not to. Using the main configuration is musch fasteer at runtime and much easier to debug and to configure.

Comment: Still no luck. I can't change the main system configuration, so I have to do it this way.

Comment: Then you will have to take a closer look at what is going on. First: how does the request to the favicon _really_ look like? What url is requested? What should the request be rewritten into? So where is the favicon really located? Sorry, but the code is fine, there must be something in your situation which differs from what is expected.

Comment: Ok, I didn't change anything but now it works, I think it had something todo with caching. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Add this `RewriteCond` before your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
```